# The most efficient way to convert a sequence of numbers to a sequence of letters

Tags: string, algorithm

Given the following mapping:

```
0->J, 1->I, 2->H, 3->G , 4->F, 5->E, 6->D, 7->C, 8->B, 9->A
```

And also given a numeric string, the expected output would be the latter mapped accordingly.

E.g. If the input is "2018", the expected ouput is "HJIB".

**My question is:** is there a procedure more efficient than the straightforward approach of iterating each character of the input string and map it? More specifically, I would like to know if I can do better than something like:

```
String output="";
for(int i=0; i<input.length(); i++) {
 output=output+map(input.charAt(0));
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by efficiency? Do you mean the time consumption of the process or the amount of storage? A look-up is always faster than a function call and a bitwise operation is always faster than a look-up. Pre-allocating the resulting string can also be faster depending on the memory management of the underlying system.

Answer (score 1):

Savings are possible in the part you have not shown (I assume `map` is a function).

Initialize an array with the mapping, i.e. m[0] = 'J', m[1] = 'I', ...

Then do `m[input.charAt(i)]` instead of `map(input.charAt(i))`.

And of course use a `StringBuilder` instead of the string concatenation (assuming this is Java).

Comment: you can initialize the array in one shot, otherwise i guess you have covered everything else.

Comment: I was already accounting with those savings, my question is if there are alternative approaches that are more efficient